# Possible to hide some parameters in URL with Angular UI Router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to pass two values to new ui-view via params:

- item id
- list of objects

However, I'd like the new view to show only the id in the browser URL and not the stringified array of objects:

```
http://www.myapp.com/#/my-view/4

INSTEAD OF

http://www.myapp.com/#/my-view/4?flskdjalfjaewoijoijasdlfkjösldakjföliwejöorijo
```

Is it possible to either a) pass the array of objects hidden to the ui-view or b) pass both but hide the other from the browser URL?

I found something about the squash parameter, but couldn't get it to do what I'm trying.

Here's my view:

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('show', {
    url: "/show/{itemId}?{itemList}",
    views: {
      'mainView': {
        templateUrl: 'views/itemView.html',
        controller: 'showController',
        params: {
          itemList: {
            value: null,
            squash: true
          },

          itemId: -1
        }
      }
    }
```

How can I hide the list of objects from the URL, without hiding the id?

Comment: If you are passing between angular views, why not make `itemList` a service instead of trying to pass it as a param?

Comment: Ah good idea... maybe this would be better especially when passing big data amounts. When passing data via params between views, are they always passed via URL or does ui router just display them there but pass it smarter behind the scenes? I'm just thinking if the url field length limitations come into play eventually...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are on the right path. To hide params you have to define them in `params` as you do, without `squash`.

Your example should look like:

```
  $stateProvider
  .state('show', {
    url: "/show?itemId",
    views: {
      'mainView': {
        templateUrl: 'views/itemView.html',
        controller: 'showController'
        // params do not work here! They need to be attached below ...
        // $stateProvider.state('show', {url:'/show/:url_param',views:{}, params: {}})
      }
    },
    resolve: {},
    params: {
      itemList: {
        value: null
      }
    }
  })
```

See example: http://plnkr.co/edit/wEjwCVWMKTyuSdyLr0og?p=preview

Comment: Ah, thanks! Hmm, I can't get it work exactly yet, maybe it's because I have to use dynamic links so I can't use ui-sref in the source file. For some reason I can't see the itemList in the new state, only itemId is being passed. Here's how I'm passing it:

<a ng-href="{{ $state.href('show', { itemList: filteredSearchResults, itemId: item.id }) }}">

The config is like this: url: "/show/{itemId}" and params: { itemList: null }

Comment: You have to pass itemList as an object:  <a ng-href="{{ $state.href('show', { itemList: {filteredSeachResults: filteredSearchResults}, itemId: item.id }) }}">

Comment: if I mention `null` I am loosing its value. What if want to use it in the `someState`'s controller?

Answer (score 2):

It's also possible doing that

**SomeController:**

```
$state.go(someState, {
 'itemId'   : item._id,
 'itemName' : item.title
});
```

**SomeRoute**
    function someRoute($stateProvider) {

```
    $stateProvider
      .state('someState', {
        url : '/:itemName',
        params : {
          'itemId' : null //hides itemId param
        }
      });
}
```

**Output:** `.../itemnumber1`

Comment: if I mention `null` I am loosing its value. What if want to use it in the `someState`'s controller?

Comment: They get just initialized to null. One you set them, you can easily access them through **$state.params**, **$state.params.itemName**.

Comment: How can I set them?

Comment: Doing like I did in SomeController. If you do, var item = new Object(); item._id = "hey"; and item.title = "Johnny"; and Then you do that precise $state.go, you'll get .../hey/Johnny.

Comment: I am sending parameters using `$state.go('myState', {name: 'ram', id: 2})`
Now, state should be `.state('myState', {url: '/home/:name', params: {id: null}})`, if I mention null like this I am loosing its value. how to set it and how to use it in the controller?

Comment: Try to understand my problem. I am trying to send two params to stateParams. one should be shown in the url and other should be used in the controller