# Ui-Router optional parameters create long not so friendly url

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My `ui-router` optional parameters create a long not so friendly url, how do I shorten the url while persisting my parameters. I need to be able to share this url over social media, be SEO friendly.

If I remove some of the parameters from my url in my state it still goes through to my view displays the correct data, but on refresh only the data from the parameters that I included in my url is displayed.

My link:

```
<a class = "xtradetails" ng-click = "vm.detailsClick(car)">VIEW DETAILS</a>
```

JS:

```
vm.detailsClick = function (car) {
    vm.detailsdata    = car;
    $state.params.car = car;
    $state.go("cardetails", {
        car          : car,
        stock_id     : car.stock_id,
        make         : car.make,
        year         : car.year,
        mileage      : car.mileage,
        variant      : car.variant,
        selling_price: car.selling_price,
        colour       : car.colour,
        condition    : car.condition,
        branch       : car.branch,
        extras_csv   : car.extras_csv,
        description  : car.description,
        location     : car.location,
        body_type    : car.body_type,
        province     : car.province,
        company_id   : car.company_id,
        url1         : car.url1,
        url2         : car.url2,
        url3         : car.url3,
        url4         : car.url4,
        url5         : car.url5,
        url6         : car.url6,
        url7         : car.url7,
        url8         : car.url8,
        url9         : car.url9,
        url10        : car.url10
    }, {});
};
```

Here is my state:

```
.state("cardetails", {
    params     : {
        car          : null,
        make         : null,
        stock_id     : null,
        company_id   : null,
        year         : null,
        selling_price: null,
        mileage      : null,
        variant      : null,
        colour       : null,
        condition    : null,
        branch       : null,
        extras_csv   : null,
        description  : null,
        province     : null,
        contact_tel  : null,
        url1         : null,
        url2         : null,
        url3         : null,
        url4         : null,
        url5         : null,
        url6         : null,
        url7         : null,
        url8         : null,
        url9         : null,
        url10        : null,
        squash       : true
    },
    templateUrl: "partials/cardetails.html",
    url        : "/:make/:stock_id/:year/:selling_price/:mileage/:variant/:colour/:condition/:location/:province/:body_type/:branch/:extras_csv/:description/:url1/:url2/:url3/:url4/:url5/:url6/:url7/:url8/:url9/:url10",
    controller : "Details"
})
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('Details', ["$scope", "$stateParams", function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.car            = $stateParams.car;
    $scope.stock_id       = $stateParams.stock_id;
    $scope.make           = $stateParams.make;
    $scope.year           = $stateParams.year;
    $scope.variant        = $stateParams.variant;
    $scope.mileage        = $stateParams.mileage;
    $scope.colour         = $stateParams.colour;
    $scope.condition      = $stateParams.condition;
    $scope.selling_price  = $stateParams.selling_price;
    $scope.branch         = $stateParams.branch;
    $scope.extras_csv     = $stateParams.extras_csv;
    $scope.description    = $stateParams.description;
    $scope.location       = $stateParams.location;
    $scope.body_type      = $stateParams.body_type;
    $scope.company_id     = $stateParams.company_id;
    $scope.contact_number = $stateParams.contact_number;
    $scope.address        = $stateParams.address;
    $scope.dealer         = $stateParams.dealer;
    $scope.suburb         = $stateParams.suburb;
    $scope.province       = $stateParams.province;
    $scope.contact_tel    = $stateParams.contact_tel;
    $scope.name           = $stateParams.name;
    $scope.url1           = $stateParams.url1;
    $scope.url2           = $stateParams.url2;
    $scope.url3           = $stateParams.url3;
    $scope.url4           = $stateParams.url4;
    $scope.url5           = $stateParams.url5;
    $scope.url6           = $stateParams.url6;
    $scope.url7           = $stateParams.url7;
    $scope.url8           = $stateParams.url8;
    $scope.url9           = $stateParams.url9;
    $scope.url10          = $stateParams.url10;
    $scope.car            = {
        make          : $scope.make,
        stock_id      : $scope.stock_id,
        company_id    : $scope.company_id,
        dealer        : $scope.dealer,
        year          : $scope.year,
        variant       : $scope.variant,
        mileage       : $scope.mileage,
        selling_price : $scope.selling_price,
        colour        : $scope.colour,
        condition     : $scope.condition,
        branch        : $scope.branch,
        extras_csv    : $scope.extras_csv,
        description   : $scope.description,
        location      : $scope.location,
        body_type     : $scope.body_type,
        contact_number: $scope.contact_number,
        address       : $scope.address,
        suburb        : $scope.suburb,
        province      : $scope.province,
        contact_tel   : $scope.contact_tel,
        name          : $scope.name,
        url1          : $scope.url1,
        url2          : $scope.url2,
        url3          : $scope.url3,
        url4          : $scope.url4,
        url5          : $scope.url5,
        url6          : $scope.url6,
        url7          : $scope.url7,
        url8          : $scope.url8,
        url9          : $scope.url9,
        url10         : $scope.url10
    };
}]);
```

Comment: You could hide some parameters with 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37425383/possible-to-hide-some-parameters-in-url-with-angular-ui-router. But it would be better if you save some data in a service/factory

Comment: thank you, will take a look at your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

In order for your application to work correctly, you need all of your parameters be to present in the URL. Now if you wish to have a more appealing URL to share on social media, there are several online services for URL shortening that you can use.

I suggest you use the [google URL shortener](https://goo.gl/). For example this question has a relatively long URL:

> https:\\stackoverflow.com/questions/46789070/ui-router-optional-parameters-create-long-not-so-friendly-url

Which becomes after shortening:

> https:\\goo.gl/QhQWCz

**NB:** please note that I have added inverted slashes to the URLs to avoid having them interpreted as clickable links.

Comment: Thank you, will alos take a look at your suggestion, just one question though, might be a bit stupid but how i use google URL shortener in my angular application?

Comment: You can't, you just use this tool if you want to share a specific URL on social media, it won't shorten all your URLs.

Comment: Thank you, my problem is these links are in an ng-repeat and gets created dynamically on the item. I have tried @Tobias Timm suggestion but I still get all the parameters in my url unfortuantely.

Comment: Is there maybe a way I can check if for example the stock_id exist only pull the data for that object without creating such a long url

Comment: Have you tried making your optional parameters declared as optional in the `url` attribute ? It would look something like this: `[/:make][/:stock_id][/:year][/:selling_price][/...`.

Comment: I have changed my url to look like this:
    <a class = "xtradetails" ui-sref="cardetails[/:year][/:company_id][/:contact_tel][/:dealer][/:selling_price][/:contact_number][/:mileage][/:variant][/:colour][/:condition][/:suburb][/:address][/:location][/:province][/:body_type][/:branch][/:extras_csv][/:description][/:url1][/:url2][/:url3][/:url4][/:url5][/:url6][/:url7][/:url8][/:url9][/:url10]" ng-click = "vm.detailsClick(car)">VIEW DETAILS</a>

Comment: No that is not what I meant, I meant in the `url` attribute of your `.state()` definition.

Comment: If I change my URL like so: url        : "/:make/:stock_id[/:year][/:company_id][/:contact_tel][/:dealer][/:selling_price][/:contact_number][/:mileage][/:variant][/:colour][/:condition][/:suburb][/:address][/:location][/:province][/:body_type][/:branch][/:extras_csv][/:description][/:url1][/:url2][/:url3][/:url4][/:url5][/:url6][/:url7][/:url8][/:url9][/:url10]", I just get a blank page, no error

Comment: Well if you get a blank page then obviously those supposedly optional url attributes are not optional after all.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me, show all the details with only the parameters i need in my url, while persisting on refresh. Maybe some else would benefit from this.

Function:

```
 vm.detailsClick     = function (car) {
               vm.detailsdata           = car;
               $state.params.car        = car;
               $state.transitionTo("cardetails", {
                   stock_id  : car.stock_id,
                   series    : car.series,
                   make      : car.make,
                   year      : car.year,
                   company_id: car.company_id,
                   selling_price: car.selling_price
               }, {});
           };
```

My state:

```
.state("cardetails", {
           url        : "/for-sale/used/:company_id/:stock_id/:make/:series/:year/:selling_price",
           params     : {
               car          : null,
               company_id   : null,
               stock_id     : null,
               year         : null,
               make         : null,
               series       : null,
               selling_price: null
           },
           resolve    : {
               car: function ($stateParams) {
                   return {
                       car          : $stateParams.car,
                       stock_id     : $stateParams.stock_id,
                       company_id   : $stateParams.company_id,
                       make         : $stateParams.make,
                       year         : $stateParams.year,
                       series       : $stateParams.series,
                       selling_price: $stateParams.selling_price
                   }
               }
           },
           controller : "Details",
           templateUrl: "partials/cardetails.html"
       })
```

My Controller:

```
app.controller('Details', ["$scope", "$http", "$stateParams", function ($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
    function detailsFetch(company_id, stock_id, selling_price) {
        var dataUrlBasePath = "you-api-url?select=*";
        $http.get(dataUrlBasePath + "&company_id=eq." + $stateParams.company_id + "&stock_id=eq." + $stateParams.stock_id + "&selling_price=eq." + $stateParams.selling_price).then(function (response) {
            $scope.car = response.data[0];
            console.log($scope.car);
        });
    }

    detailsFetch($stateParams.company_id, $stateParams.stock_id, $stateParams.selling_price);
}]);
```